# Pre-count filtered results in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a long list of products that are displayed using ng-repeat and I'm creating a filter on the left to pare down the list in the main content well.

I have a requirement to pre-count the results of each possible filter such that the text of the link of that filter button will show the results you will receive if you turn that filter on, just like happens in an e-commerce site.

I'm wondering how to do this with AngularJS.  I'm hoping there's an easier way to do this other than creating a custom filter on the scope for each possible filter.

Note that I don't have to worry about chaining filter values- just the results of selecting that one filter.

Thanks, Scott

Comment: I'm not sure if the possible filters are static or not, but this sounds like a case where it'd be better to let the server do the work. Have an api call that returns each filter and the # of matches, then just render them as you've described using ng-repeat.

Comment: Why would you create filters on the scope? Just count the items satisfying the predicate of your filters in the controller, and store the result value along with the predicate and the name of the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing exactly what the data model looks like I can't say if you need a custom filter.  But for a simple data model you should be able to use a simple filter like so:

`<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a ng-click="filter(item.type)">{{item.name}} {{(allData | filter:item.type).length}}</a>
   </li>
</ul>`

Here is a working example http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/GqpqYN

Comment: Woohoo! That's perfect! Thanks!